# What is breaking the scroll on my site? (touch only)

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, scroll, touch

So I've built a website and everything is going fine except one thing. When you go to the shop page on a mobile and hit "**filter products**" *(only visible on screens up to 1000px wide)*, the filter menu that slides out doesn't scroll.

If you try it on your laptop using the mouse wheel it will scroll fine, but go on your phone (or get the chrome inspector to mimic a touch device) and you'll see it doesn't scroll any more when you touch the screen, only with the mouse wheel.

Here is the page in question: https://growitmowit.co.uk/shop/

I have tried ripping the css & js out but once you've clicked "filter products" and the menu has slided out you cannot scroll (with touch) until you slide the filter menu away.

I've now spent hours trying to figure it out and need some help :) Thank you in advance.

*oh yeah - sometimes, when you first open the page with the inspector in device mode it is fine. If that's the case refresh the page and it'll start playing up :(*

Comment: Maybe this read can help: http://chris-barr.com/2010/05/scrolling_a_overflowauto_element_on_a_touch_screen_device/

Comment: @Valius79 cheers - I've already read that and tried the -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; css trick. but that doesn't fix anything in this situation I'm afraid.